# Проблемы с передачей функции как параметр

Tags: c++

есть класс, с необходимой мне функцией:

```
class LinearAllocator : public Allocator<LinearAllocator>
{
public:
    ...
    IAllocatable* allocate(std::size_t size, std::size_t alignment = 0); // CRTP 
    ...
};
```

Также есть функция, которая должна примять параметром эту функцию:

```
char* readFile(const char* fullFileName, std::function<Memory::IAllocatable*(std::size_t, std::size_t)>) noexcept;
```

Пробую передать функцию следующим образом:

```
Memory::LinearAllocator allocator(32768); 
char* buffer = Utils::readFile(name, std::bind(&Memory::LinearAllocator::allocate, &allocator));
```

В связи с этим я получаю следующую ошибку:

```
Error   C2664   'char *Utils::readFile(const char *,std::function<Memory::IAllocatable *(size_t,size_t)>) noexcept': cannot convert argument 2 from 'std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,Memory::IAllocatable *(__thiscall Memory::LinearAllocator::* )(size_t,size_t) noexcept,Memory::LinearAllocator *>' to 'std::function<Memory::IAllocatable *(size_t,size_t)>'
```

Никак не могу понять в чем может быть проблема...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char* buffer = Utils::readFile
(
    name
,   ::std::bind
    (
        &Memory::LinearAllocator::allocate
    ,   &allocator
    ,   ::std::placeholders::_1
    ,   ::std::placeholders::_2
    )
);
```

или

```
char* buffer = Utils::readFile
(
    name
,   [&allocator](::std::size_t size, ::std::size_t alignment) -> IAllocatable*      
    {
        return allocator.allocate(size, alignment);
    }
);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, как же я забыл про аргументы...